# How do I change default code formatter in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter-lab, autopep8

There is some information [here](https://jupyterlab-code-formatter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-use.html#changing-default-formatter), but it's not clear where to put the code.
My main task is to use black or autopep8 formatter for the whole notebook